# Gcloud kubernetes nginx unable to find upstream host after cluster upgrade

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

I have just upgraded my cluster and nodes to v1.7.12 and recreated all pods successfully except for my nginx pod which keeps on failing with the error:

```
nginx   2018-02-17T08:38:07.965745644Z  nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "gunicorn" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/web.conf:8
nginx   2018-02-17T08:38:07.965678149Z  2018/02/17 08:enter code here38:07 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "gunicorn" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/web.conf:8
```

The idea is that my nginx pod reverse proxies to my gunicorn pods which was working prior to the cluster upgrade.

I have very limited understanding of kubernetes as I wasn't the one who configured the infrastructure.

My suspicion is I am missing a configuration when the cluster and nodes were upgraded but I don't know what.

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out. Apparently I have different configurations for my gunicorn pods and gunicorn service. I simply missed starting up the gunicorn service.

Comment: Mark your answer as solution, it may help others.

Comment: @JohannesM Will do but I have to wait 2 days before I can mark my own answer as a solution.